# Delete white space between divs

Tags: css, html

I'm getting some strange whitespace between two divs I have.

Each div has the css property `display: inline-block` and each have a set height and width.

I cannot find where the whitespace is.

[Here is a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RVAQp/1/)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You get whitespace there because you have whitespace inbetween the divs. Whitespace between inline elements is interpreted as a space.

You have:

```
<div id="left_side">
    <div id="plan">
        <h1>div 1</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="right_side">
    <div id="news">
        <h1>div 2</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Change for:

```
<div id="left_side">
    <div id="plan">
        <h1>div 1</h1>
    </div>
</div><div id="right_side">
    <div id="news">
        <h1>div 2</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, this is a bad way to do what you want to do.

You should float the elements if thats what you want to do.

Comment: Nowadays %widths and height are preferred for your website to work perfectly on all devices.

Comment: Edited. My comment (made almost 4 years ago) was made at a time when "liquid layout" was a poor design choice. Nowadays % width/height works well for responsive web design.

Comment: you sir are a legend !!

Answer (score 23):

Use:

```
float:left;
clear:none;
```

In both `div`

Answer (score 12):

If you want to retain your coding layout, avoid floats and keep each div on it's own line entirely...

`<div id="leftSide">Some content here</div><!--
--><div id="rightSide">Some more content here</div>`

Answer (score 6):

Only add this to your CSS

```
h1 {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
   }
```

Space between div is only due to h1 Margin and Padding

Comment: If you have two divs without padding and margin one near another there are two cases: a) if the html is minimzed (no space between tags) then the divs will be adjacent. b) if there is a single space/tab/enter then the browser shows a small space between those divs. Your answer does not respond user's question. I made time to write a small explanation so you might understand the difference. Kudos!

Comment: Just `margin: 0;` seems to work in most cases. No need for `padding:0;` unless that element already has padding.

Answer (score 5):

This does the trick:

```
<div id="left_side">
    ...
</div><div id="right_side">
    ...
</div>
```

Notice how the right-side div starts immediately after the closing tag of the left-side div. This works because any space between the elements, since they are now inline, would become a space in the layout itself. You can mirror this behavior with two span elements.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/RVAQp/7/).

Answer (score 5):

You can also add `display: flex;` to the divs' parent container (in this case, `body`). [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hdodov/s7wotazp/1/).

Comment: Since the question relates to `display: inline-block` I would rather suggest `display: inline-flex`.

Comment: I second that, @Sunny

Answer (score 2):

best way is settings parent element's font-size to 0 then normal font-size to child elements inside that parent (otherwise inherits zero from parent)

Answer (score 1):

Floated both of the elements left, also made the 30% width into 40% to fill all the space, but this isn't necessary. Please be aware, "inline-block" isn't supported by IE7 but can be fixed with a workaround.

http://jsfiddle.net/RVAQp/3/

Comment: This, of course, is another option. Though it should be noted the floated elements should be cleared.

Comment: Good points, but really doesn't answer the OP's question. This is really a comment that should go on the question, rather than an answer.

Comment: You're completely right, I sort of missed the point with this one.

Answer (score 1):

Move these statements onto the same line:

```
</div><div id="right_side">
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried using float instead of "inline-block", no problems.  Just changed the display:inline-block to:

```
#left_side {float: left;}
```

and

```
#right_side {float: right; margin-right: 10%}
```

No apparent problems.  Could be wrong.

Comment: Floats and inline-blocks (as well as table-cells and flexible boxes) are fundamentally different things. All four techniques *may be* suitable for horizontal alignment of items, but they have different limitations and downsides. In theory, flexboxes seem to be the most universal way of the four, but browsers support of the latest spec version is still rather limited.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why but I resolved this problem by adding `border: 1px solid red;`(vertical) and `float: left;`(horizontal) to related DIV style statement and  white-spaces removed.

Answer (score 0):

Parent div set to font-size: 0px and chiilds to wanted size like 17px :)