# Placing 2 50% width input elements in a row, understanding box-sizing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to place 2 `input` elements inline with 50% width each. Why do I have to subtract the border width from the `input` elements even when I use `box-sizing: border-box`?

http://jsfiddle.net/Nmvk6/

`HTML`

```
<form class="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Type</label>
        <button class="btn btn-default">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control half-width-form-control">
            <option value="foo">foo</option>
            <option value="bar">bar</option>
        </select>
        <input class="form-control half-width-form-control" type="number"></input>
    </div>
</form>
```

`CSS`

```
.half-width-form-control {
   display: inline-block;
    width: calc(50% - 2px);
    /*width: 50%;*/
    /*box-sizing: border-box;*/
}
```

Comment: Good questionm although this has nothing to do wwith bootstrap itself. It's a little hard to see in your question that you rather ask details about `box-sizing` and less about basic element positioning. Maybe think of a more apropriate title.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delete white space between divs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555240/delete-white-space-between-divs)

Comment: Its always a good practice to use float {left/right} with overflow hidden... It solves unknown complications...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you have here is related to `inline-block`.

`display:inline-block` tells the browser to treat the element as a block with regard to its contents, but as an inline element with regard to its surroundings.

The problem for you here is that the surrounding around the two elements includes some white space. Specifically, you have some white space between the two elements. White space is relevant for `inline` elements, and thus also for `inline-block` elements.

In a nutshell, it's as if the two elements were words in a sentence. The white space between them is seen as the space between two words.

What you end up with is `50% width` + `width of one space character` + `50% width`.

This is a well-known issue with `inline-block`, but does trip people up a lot.

The quick+dirty solution is therefore to remove the space -- close up the gap between the end of the `<select>` and the begining of the `<input>` so that there is no space there.

Other alternatives include using comments to remove the gap (ugly), styling the container element to `font-size:0px;`, and various other hacky solutions.

Alternatively, you could throw away the inline-blocks. There are a number of other options which can achieve the same or similar results -- notably `float`, `display:table-cell`, and `flex-box`, but others also exist.

But my suggestion is just to remove the spaces between the two elements. Quick, easy fix.

Comment: Hm, my answer was too short, obviously. Congrats!

Answer (score 3):

Two issues:

1. You need `-webkit-box-sizing` and `-moz-box-sizing` if you want to make it work on all current browsers. See [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).
2. There was a space (actually a return and some spaces, but they collapse to 1 space) between the two controls, so the total width was 100% plus the space.

Solution: add the prefixed properties and remove the space from the markup.

http://jsfiddle.net/Nmvk6/7/

Answer (score 2):

Specify

```
float:left
```

And it fixes it.

http://jsfiddle.net/Nmvk6/8/

Comment: But you will lose the margin effect from form-group as float elements do not apply, so you must add `margin-bottom: 15px;` to maintain the spacing.