# White spaces in between each div won't go away [CSS]

Tags: jquery, html, css, whitespace

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head>
        <title>Test Menu</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css'/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <a href="index.html"><div id="home">Home</div></a>
        <a href="about.html"><div id="about">About Us</div></a>
        <a href="contact.html"><div id="contact">Contact</div></a>
        </body>
</html>
```

stylesheet.css:

```
div {
    background-color: #B3B3B3;
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
    display:inline;
    font-size:20px;
    padding:15px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    padding-right:7px;
    padding-left:7px;
    border:2px solid black;
    color:black;
    position:relative;
}
a{
    text-decoration:none;
}
.active {
    background-color:#556677;
}
```

script.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //hover menu
    $('div').hover(function(){
        $(this).addClass('active');
    },function(){
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

If you were to run this, it would look like [this](http://gyazo.com/8be71d57b2cafd341e5dcfaa3c65e0c8). However, I want it like that, but without any of the white space. I realize `float:left`; would kind of solve this, but I don't want the white space on the far left and I want the border to overlap (i.e so it doesn't join together and become 4px on the edges)

Thank you for any and all help!

EDIT: Thanks you all so much for helping, I understand my problem and how to fix it a lot more now!

Comment: You can use http://jsfiddle.net/ next time :D

Comment: try to use inline-block and remove the white space between dives [info link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14241696/how-to-get-rid-of-space-between-divs-when-display-inline-block-and-stacked-horiz).Don't use float until you just need the images flow following the text or versus. [the differences ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15172520/drawback-of-css-displayinline-block-vs-floatleft)

Comment: Don't put block-level elements (`<div>`) inside inline-level ones (`<a>`) for starters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited:**

First of all do not put a block level `div` element inside an inline element `a`. Use an inline element `span` instead of block element `div`

**Your Issue:**

You have applied css attribute `display:inline` on a `div` tag. When you use an inline elements it takes extra margins. To remove those margins there is a quick fix given below:

HTML:

```
<div class="nav">
    <a href="#">some text</a>
    <a href="#">some text</a>
    <a href="#">some text</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.nav { 
    font-size: 0px; /* set font size 0px to remove white-space of child inline elements */ 
    overflow: hidden; /*for auto height*/ 
}

a { 
    background-color: #B3B3B3;
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:20px;
    padding:10px;
    border-top:2px solid black;
    border-bottom:2px solid black;
    border-right:2px solid black;
    color:black;
    position:relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

a:first-child { border-left:2px solid black; }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/TKXeL/)

Answer (score 1):

This looks ugly but try this, note that there's no newline every `<a>`

```
<a href="index.html"><div id="home">Home</div></a><a href="about.html"><div id="about">About Us</div></a><a href="contact.html"><div id="contact">Contact</div></a>
```

[Here's a fiddle demo I talked about! :D](http://jsfiddle.net/LDWGf/)

[It's because newlines are interpreted as whitespace :)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555240/delete-white-space-between-divs)

Comment: I think, Its not a good idea. Code should be clear in separate lines.

Comment: Yeah I know, it's ugly :/

Answer (score 1):

Define float:left; in your DIV CSS. i.e.

```
div {
  background-color: #B3B3B3;
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
  display:inline;
  font-size:20px;
  padding:15px;
  padding-bottom:5px;
  padding-right:7px;
  padding-left:7px;
  border:2px solid black;
  color:black;
  position:relative;
  float:left; 
}
```

Also Include below CSS for to show proper border's width :

```
#home { border-right:0px;}
#contact { border-left:0px;}
```

JsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/LDWGf/2/

Answer (score 0):

try this short codes -

**HTML CODE -**

```
<div>
    <a href="index.html" id="home">Home</a>
    <a href="about.html" id="about">About Us</a>
    <a href="contact.html" class="last" id="contact">Contact</a>
</div>
```

**CSS CODE -**

```
div{ display:inline-block;}
a{
    float:left;
    padding:8px 15px;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:13px;
    color:#000;
    border:1px solid #000;
    border-right:0px;
    background:#b3b3b3;
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
}

.last{
    border-right:1px solid #000;
}

.active {
    background-color:#556677;
}
```

Resolved example - [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ptM6G/3/)

Comment: that gets rid of the blank spaces in between but the one to the left is still there. also the lines double up, is there a way to make them overlap instead?

Comment: perfect except for the blank spaces above and to the left

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 solutions for this issue 1st is simply add this css

```
body{ font-size:0;}
```

and in 2nd you have 2 remove space from html like below

```
<a href="index.html"><div id="home">Home</div></a><a href="about.html"><div id="about">About Us</div></a><a href="contact.html"><div id="contact">Contact</div></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the answers given above. You can simply wrap white-spaces with HTML comment as following:

```
<div>
    <a href="index.html" id="home">Home</a><!--
    --><a href="about.html" id="about">About Us</a><!--
    --><a href="contact.html" class="last" id="contact">Contact</a>
</div>
```

This will keep your html clean and you need not use `float:left;`

Checkout the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mBPq8/) here

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking for.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul { font-size: 0; }

li { display: inline-block; }

li + li { margin-left: -2px; }

a {
    display: block;
    background: #B3B3B3;
    transition: 0.5s;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 15px 7px 5px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover { background: #556677; }
```

To get rid of the space between the menu items, we're setting the `font-size` to `0` on it's parent container (the `ul` tag). However, since we want the font to be visible on the menu items themselves (the `<a>` tags), we've over-ridden the `font-size` on them to `20px`.

To get rid of the 4px wide border between menu items, I've used the [CSS adjacent-sibling selector](http://meyerweb.com/eric/articles/webrev/200007a.html) to add a negative margin that gets rid of the extra-wide border.

I've also updated the markup structure of the menu to be more sound as well as removed the JavaScript class-powered hovers and replaced them with a pure-CSS version.

Here's a working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/galengidman/Qc9Cz/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

[Check out this demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a6AG2/6/)

What I have added is this:

```
a{
text-decoration:none;
float:left;
}

*{margin:0;padding:0}//to remove the start white space
```