# how can remove white space in drop down menu

Tags: html

I tried creating my own text editor in ASP.NET Core MVC. everything is worked fine but I have some problem in my style.

As you can see in Image below I have one text color Button with 9 default color and one color picker. But After a lot of trial and error, I came up with the following code and still have some empty space between buttons. (I put the gray color for drop down menu background so I can see clearly if the empty space fill or not. ) how can fix this? also it seems no mater how many I try the size of drop down menu it can not be smaller from specific value.
how can I fix this too?

[image]

```
    <div class="btn-group   " style="position:static;  z-index: 9999">
        <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle " data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style=" z-index: 9999;">
            <img src="~/assets/theme/text-color.png" style="width:20px;height:20px;" />
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu text-end " style="background-color:lightgrey; z-index:9999">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4 pe-0  ">
                    <button id="@Model.button" class=" w-100    rounded-0 border border-dark " data-element="foreColor" style="height:20px;background-color:white" data-value="white">
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4 p-0 ">

                    <button id="@Model.button" class=" w-100    rounded-0 border border-dark " data-element="foreColor" style="height:20px;background-color:black" data-value="black">
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4 ps-0">

                    <button id="@Model.button" class=" w-100   rounded-0 border border-dark" data-element="foreColor" style="height:20px;background-color:red" data-value="red">
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4 pe-0">

                    <button id="@Model.button" class=" w-100  rounded-0 border border-dark" data-element="foreColor" style="height:20px;background-color:yellow" data-value="yellow">
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4 p-0">

                    <button id="@Model.button" class=" w-100  rounded-0 border border-dark " data-element="foreColor" style="height:20px;background-color:blue" data-value="blue">
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4 ps-0">
                    <button id="@Model.button" class=" w-100 rounded-0 border border-dark" data-element="foreColor" style="height:20px;background-color:green" data-value="green">
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4 pe-0">
                    <button id="@Model.button" class="w-100  rounded-0 border border-dark" data-element="foreColor" style="height:20px;background-color:purple" data-value="purple">
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4 p-0">
                    <button id="@Model.button" class=" w-100  rounded-0 border border-dark" data-element="foreColor" style="height:20px;background-color:brown" data-value="brown">
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4 ps-0">
                    <button id="@Model.button" class=" w-100  rounded-0 border border-dark" data-element="foreColor" style="height:20px;background-color:pink" data-value="pink">
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 py-0">
                    <input id="@Model.button" class=" w-100  " type="color" name="foreColor" value="#AABBCC">
                   @* <button id="@Model.button" class=" w-100  rounded-0 border border-dark" data-element="foreColor" style="height:20px;">
                    </button>*@
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do the following:

Instead of:

```html
<div class="col-4 pe-0">
    <button id="@Model.button" class=" w-100 rounded-0 border border-dark" data-element="foreColor" style="height:20px;background-color:white" data-value="white"></button>
</div>
<div class="col-4 p-0">
    <button id="@Model.button" class=" w-100 rounded-0 border border-dark" data-element="foreColor" style="height:20px;background-color:black" data-value="black"></button>
</div>
```

Do this:

```html
<div class="col-4 pe-0  ">
    <button id="@Model.button" class=" w-100    rounded-0 border border-dark " data-element="foreColor" style="height:20px;background-color:white" data-value="white"></button>
</div><div class="col-4 p-0 ">
    <button id="@Model.button" class=" w-100    rounded-0 border border-dark " data-element="foreColor" style="height:20px;background-color:black" data-value="black"></button>
</div>
```

Simply the white space is there because there is a whitespace between the divs in your HTML code. "*Whitespace between inline elements is interpreted as a space.*" referenced from this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9555265/15469806)

You can "[float](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)" your elements as well if you want.

e.g.:

```html
<div class="col-04" style="float:left;">
    ...
</div>
<div class="col-05" style="float:left;">
    ...
</div>
```